# Generate automatic PDF letter with input form from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, automation

I want to generate a PDF letter using some fields e.g. name, nationality etc. that the user will submit using a form on a WordPress website. The letter has a certain template and only these fields change depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Without much detail in the question or knowledge of access to code (API) in Wordpress, you could use an API like [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org//)

Via JetPack perhaps?